Are retrocomputers best left on or off?
I have a machine from 1998. I believe its hard drive and RAM are all original. It powers on and loads the OS, so I have reason to believe that nothing major is corrupted. However, is it best to leave it on once it is on, or to power it down unless I'm using it?
I intend to use it for about 1 hour per day. My reasoning for turning it off is to not stress the components for longer than they have to be, but my reasoning for leaving it on is that the surge of power every time it turns on might be worse. Are there any guidelines for this?
It's a custom-built machine from one of those little computer shops that doesn't exist anymore, so I can't say much about it other than it allegedly has a Pentium II in it.
EDIT:
To the comment: I do not know which type of power supply. I mean "leave it off" as in go to Start->Shutdown, but leaving it plugged in.

What machine? A PC, but AT or ATX supply? What do you mean by leaving it on or off, as there is a difference between "off" as in unplugged from mains, "off" as in powered from mains but in soft-off state where it simply turns on with soft-power button? Leaving a 1998 PC on for weeks unused with spinning hard drives does not sound like a good idea, or do you mean some sleep state? It's really hard to guess what you might mean.

@Justme I have edited the question

AIUI, it isn't "a surge of power". But rather, motors in particular have the most stress (and power usage) when starting, which applies to the power supply fan, any other fans and, most critical, the hard drive. In ye olden times (80s) hard drives on and off would be issues, but by 1998 that should have been resolved with the drive automatically parking the heads in any normal shutdown.

The edit is useless if you don't know the supply type. Does the front panel have a physical mains switch or is it a just a pushbutton? Huge difference regarding a power surge to the input of the supply. The output will have only very small surge as the voltage output from switch mode power supply has some finite slew rate. If I had to guess a P2 might have ATX supply. If it can turn off itself from start menu shut down button in software, it's ATX.

@Justme I have worked on plenty of computers with "just a pushbutton" that was actually a true physical mains switch. Easy to figure out if you know what you're doing (and certainly if you can actually press the switch), but impossible to guess from a picture of the case/switch.

Another issue with turning on and off is the change in temperature as it slowly warms up and then cools down.  This thermal cycling can stress boards and components — though I don't know how much of an issue that might be in your case.

What's most important is that the equipment be used often enough that it continues to be seen as useful rather than discarded.  Anything else is secondary to that.

Superstition: I worked in DEC where we had a room full of PDP-11s that were left powered on.  Except on public holidays where they were powered off for the long weekend. There was generally one system (different each time) needing loving attention from Field Service when we powered things back up.

Will you be present all the time the machine has power?  Some failure modes are harmful to the surroundings, so leaving it unattended has risks that you don't have if you power down.  (And I speak as someone unable to work for two days following a power cut when my workstation's main fan stopped for the first time in several years and wouldn't start again).

@supercat Not sure I understand the reasoning behind your statement. If the system is actually needed to perform some functionality, then keeping it operational when overstressing components might cause failure's that can no longer be repaired would seem to me to be vastly more important than keeping it to be "seen as useful" ... what does that even mean?

@CGCampbell: My point was that the amount of 1980s computer equipment that has been scrapped for obsolescence vastly exceeds the amount that fails for any other reason.  If capacitors are viewed as a maintenance item, stuff was built well enough that wear shouldn't really be an issue.

@dave It probably needed attention because the boot ROM had degraded in the waste heat over the last week! ;-)

@MichaelStachowsky It probably needs a new CMOS battery by now. And do you have a disk image of the HDD so it isn't such a tragedy when the drive fails? Although, the computer will be much more usable if you replace the the HDD with an SSD. Which OS is it running? - some from that era didn't know to send a TRIM command to the SSD every now and again.

TL;DR: Up to your taste. There is no one way fits all.
All hardware degrades from being powered up, and it degrades from cycling. So neither is preferred. Then again, run time goes linear with wear of any moving part as well as taking in dirt from the outside. Last but not least, do you really power that hardware up that often that cycling is a notable issue? So for most cases cycling is the least degrading solution.

+1 Big difference between 1 hour a day x 365/year and 1 hour a day "occasionally".

I agree. Also '98 isn't all that "retro": you'll almost certainly be able to get spare PSUs and discs and find somebody able to repair the former. However an overall replacement plan would be strongly advised.

This is not subjective at all. You should do whatever is best for the critical components rather than what is best for the hardware overall. Some things in a computer are trivial to repair, other parts are impossible.
TL;DR: keep it turned off.
(The author of this answer has some 20+ years of experience from electronics design and repairs.)

One of the most common components to break over time are aluminum electrolyte capacitors, which you will find in any PSU old or new, and probably in the voltage regulator parts of other circuit boards around the computer. Whenever someone says that power cycling is bad, they most likely refer to the aluminum electrolyte caps (or other caps like polymer film caps), because they only conduct when the voltage is changing.
Some info about what causes them to age from a manufacturer of such components - example. Basically, they age because of voltages applied, because of cycling but particularly because of temperature. So these kind of caps definitely prefer the computer to remain turned off.
However, these are some of the easiest components to replace for someone with professional soldering experience. Don't attempt it yourself as a layman! They do hold charge for quite a long time after shutting the power off. It is also important to find a replacement part with equivalent specifications. But perfectly doable for someone with a bit of electronics knowledge.
What's nasty with aluminum electrolytes is rather that when they fail, they either do so by leaking goo all over the circuit board, or worse: fail spectacularly with a loud bang and smoke. You can avoid this if make it a habit to inspect aluminium electrolytes on a regular basis - if they start to bulge, they need to be replaced and you shouldn't power up the device until they are fixed.

Other common components likely to break are diverse forms of memories, various PROM. These come with a best before date - there's something known as data retention which is memory aging characteristics over time. This too escalates in heat.
When memories fail then that's far more severe - there's nothing you can do - the equipment is toast. (Except maybe scavenge an identical part from another device of the same kind.) The company who had the firmware for it is likely gone and they likely have no interest in keeping very old firmware around, let alone to help random collectors of retro stuff.
A PROM manufactured in the 1980s could have something like at most 10-20 years specified data retention across a temperature range up to either 70°C or 85°C. Meaning that they guarantee that the memory will stay valid for x years if you keep it below the specified temperature. Now of course we don't keep parts in a continuous heat of some 70°C, but much cooler, which is why some of these parts still work even though they are well beyond the specified data retention period. The most likely heat source is the computer itself while turned on.
Data retention is for sure a ticking bomb for all of these parts, why hobbies like collecting old video games are doomed - the only thing you know for sure is that the item will eventually fail. Could be today, could be in 10 years from now. The best way to fight it is to keep the part cool - you don't need freezing temperature, room temperature is fine, a cold basement even better. Don't leave it standing in the sun etc.

Less critical parts which are likely to fail over time are electro-mechanical parts: connectors, solder joints, cable assemblies. These definitely like the device to be turned on - a bit of current across such parts helps a lot against oxidation. However, these are also some of the most trivial parts to repair. And if they were assembled correctly back in the days, they are unlikely to cause problems even some 40 years later.

Also keep in mind that old electronics have horrible protection against electrostatic discharges (ESD), so while keeping the part dry is nice, this can also be problematic because dry air means more ESD. So if you are running the device, moist air is not necessarily a bad thing. Professional electronics assembly halls usually have air moisturizers for this very reason - it's more important to avoid ESD than to keep the parts dry.
Dust is obviously a problem too over time especially when fans are not running. A computer left turned off is likely to gather more dust on circuit boards etc. It's risky business to clean old circuit boards - just touching the boards with your fingers is a bad idea to begin with. A rule of thumb is to always touch the metal chassis first before touching anything else. You have to avoid using textile rags etc since they might cause ESD. You can buy an "ESD brush" which is basically a brush which doesn't cause ESD. For cleaning any form of mess on the board like leaks from old capacitors, use isopropyl. Water is also relatively harmless to use actually, but obviously you should never power up a device while there's water present on the circuit boards.

As a summary - it's better for some parts to be turned on and worse for other parts. But the common culprit degrading the most critical components - memories in particular - is heat. Electronics are therefore best stored cold and dry. Since all such devices produce quite a bit of heat when turned on, it is better to leave them turned off. Ideally store them in a cold basement or similar.

+1, you are only missing harddisks, fans and possibly relays under electromechanical parts. Though they mostly wear linearly with activity/runtime, so emphasize your point that turning off is better

@Michael I tried to keep this generic enough so that it applies to all manner "generic old electronic thing with some manner of software inside."

"a cold dry basement free of rodents", perhaps

while you mentioned it's more important to avoid ESD than keep the parts dry there is a delicate balance and I agree with @scruss that a dry basement must be considered... in some basements excessive humidity or even leaks can be a present causing corrosion and other problems.

I had an electrolytic capacitor fail on a (then) modern computer a few years back. It took down a bunch of other components.

@scruss Hence "Electronics are therefore best stored cold and dry."

@Michael The remarks about moisture being good for ESD are only when you are using the product, particularly when prying it open for cleaning or repairs. For storage, dry is preferred.

I have a 9-year old work laptop with a fixed hard-disk drive (HDD).  It ran perfectly fine every work day.  But then I needed it to remain on for a few days, constantly.  Right after that test, the HDD died with the heads locking in place.  I was able to replace the drive and restored the data with a back-up I regularly make.
My points: Older hard drives (my 30-year olds still function) last longer than the newer ones, from my experience.  And I've read that if HDDs are left on for a long time, do not, then, turn them off.  Back-ups are king...unless you don't mind wasting time reinstalling EVERYTHING (drivers, bookmarks, etc.), to try to get it back to the way it was.
When it comes to electronics, it all depends on the overall design(s), which you can only guess at.  (I have created moderate electronic designs as part of my job.)
Fans can sometimes (surprisingly) be brought back to quiet/life with a drop of oil under their sticky label.
Old power supplies can sometimes be repaired by replacing visibly bloated capacitors, if you know someone who knows basic electronics/soldering.

Old drives had their problems too. Some of it is survival of the fittest. Plenty of drives 30 years ago died within a week, month or year. But if they lasted a few years then they were likely to last a long time.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: you mean survivorship bias.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the bathtub curve is not unique to drives of that era

@Michael Don't put your drives in a bathtub.  That's not how you should scrub your data.


However, is it best to leave it on once it is on, or to power it down unless I'm using it?

Power it down. I'm mostly worried about the capacitors and the hard disk drive.
Surge current to power supply capacitors generally doesn't cause them to fail. However, it can blow fuses or trip circuit breakers if a huge number of devices have the surge at the same time, for example after a power outage.
There are two ways old capacitors can fail:

If they are never used for a large number of years. However, you say you use the devices regularly so that's not an issue.
If they are operating at a high temperature for a number of hours that exceeds their rating.

In your case, if you keep your devices on at all times, (2) would cause early failure of your capacitors.
If you would change your problem statement by saying that the options are to keep it always on and to keep it always off (and never turn on every couple of years for example), then I wouldn't be so certain in my opinion.
Also, old hard disk drives before the advent of laptop computer HDD technology in 3.5" HDDs can fail due to cycling but one cycle per day isn't much. Turning it on and off dozens of times per day every day could be worrying. However, a constantly spinning hard disk drive is at risk of failing.
This can be seen from the cheap "green" hard disk drives. They are generally used in cheap USB mass memories that are powered on only occasionally. If you put one of those cheap "green" HDDs to a computer that's continuously on, it can fail in few years or even faster if it's in a busy RAID array. I speak from experience (I keep my computers on at all times), and never again am I going to use those cheap "green" HDDs in such an application.

You are talking about modern "green" hard drives. They fail because they are cheap and not rated for 24/7 operation and they only come with 2 year warranty, so you are running them outside their specs, and you might get denied warranty because power-on hours exceed the rating. Old drives and old electrolytic capacitors can be tricky, they will fail eventually, either from excessively keeping them powered, or excessively keeping them unpowered.
